# Xamarin forms: How to change the top color of IOS app(Color at the phone battery icon)

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, background-color

One screenshot of my xamarin forms ios app is adding below. I want the change the color on the top part, I mean on the color at the battery icon. Currently, it is white, I need it as yellow.

[image: Screenshot]

For getting the top padding I added the following code on my XAML:

```
 <StackLayout>
    <StackLayout.Padding>
       <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" 
          Android="0, -10, 0, 0" 
          WinPhone="0, -10, 0, 0" 
          iOS="0, 15, 0, 0"/>
     </StackLayout.Padding>
 </StackLayout>
```

If I remove above code, my app icons and battery icon in the phone get overlap. So How can I change the white color on top?

Comment: @EvZ Solved this issue by using a boxview, answer updated below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a BoxView to fill the top space:

```
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout.Padding>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" 
            Android="0, -10, 0, 0" 
            iOS="0, 15, 0, 0"/>
    </StackLayout.Padding> 

    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Yellow">
        <BoxView.Margin>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="0, -30, 0, -15"/>
        </BoxView.Margin>
    </BoxView>

    <!--...
    Other controls-->

</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will resolve your issue

https://montemagno.com/ios-tip-change-status-bar-icon-text-colors/